# Victoria Metrics (single) logging lot of gibberish to syslog

Tags: victoriametrics

I have a vmsingle deployed behind an vmagent.

My syslog is now full of logs similar to this one:

```
May 25 20:38:41 victoriametrics-1 vmsingle[17279]: 2023-05-25T20:38:41.703Z#011error#011VictoriaMetrics/lib/protoparser/vmimport/parser.go:239#011cannot unmarshal json line "5\x1do\x00)6o\x00Lread_duration_second\xf2S\x01\x00aB\xb5\x04=S\x01n\x04er\xcem\x06.@\x01\bf": cannot parse json line: unexpected tail: "\x1do\x00)6o\x00Lread_duration_second\xf2S\x01\x00aB\xb5\x04=S\x01n\x04er\xcem\x06.@\x01\bf"; skipping it
```

What may be the reason and how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The error suggests that client submits a malformed payload to Insert API. In other words, client sends unexpected data. I'd recommend checking your clients  for the corresponding error messages on their side and fix the way how they push data to VictoriaMetrics.